# Print address of char pointer

Tags: linux

```
int main(){
    char a[] = "Ab";
    char *ptr = a;
    //ptr = a;
    cout << &a << a[0] << endl;
    cout << ptr << endl;

    char c= 'C';
    char *pC = &c;
    cout << &c << " :: " << pC << endl;
    cout << pC << endl;
}
```

Output :
0x7fffcb399550A
Ab
CAb :: CAb
CAb

Unable to understand last two outputs.

Answer (score 0):

`&c` and `pC` are both pointers to a single character.

`operator<<` requires its operand of type `char*` to be a pointer to a *null-terminated string*, that is, to an array of characters that contains a `\0` somewhere.

Otherwise the behaviour is *undefined*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have again some confusion .Why this same behaviour is not applied to char a[] = "ab". When we try to print &a , operator should take operand type as char*, then it should also print the string "ab" not the address. Why &a print the address of beginning of string and in case of char c = 'C' , &c print the character 'C' ?

Comment: @user3248678 `&a` is  not of type `char*` because `a` is not of type `char`.